# URL rewriting from old server to new one with IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, dns, url-rewrite-module

I have an old Sharepoint server with the domain http://intranet.contoso.com and I want to rewrite the URL to http://intranet.contoso.eu.

So I changed the IP from my DNS entry to the new server and now, if my IIS receives a request from the .com domain, I want to rewrite this to the .eu domain and als redirect the user to this site.

I tried to achieve this with URL rewrite module in IIS, but I am failing.

Can someone explain me the correct settings for DNS and the url rewrite module, so that a user will be directed to the new site and also in his browser address bar should show up the .eu domain after the rewrite.

I am on Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Added a site to the IIS with an empty directory and the same host like the old one (http://intranet.contoso.com).
2. Set the HTTP Redirect from this empty site to my Sharepoint site in IIS (http://intranet.contoso.eu). Set the "Redirect all requests to exact destination (instead of relative to destination) checkbox.
3. Changed DNS from old server to the new one.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change the url on sharepoint central administration under alternate access mappings and on the iis under edit bindings

Comment: I want to rewrite the URL completely. If the user enters the http://intranet.contoso.com site, it should rewrite the URL in browsers address bar to .eu.